# How to Split a Byte[]

Tags: c#, .net

I need to split a byte[].

I have some data in an original byte[] that would look like:

```
byte[] m_B = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0xc0, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0xc0, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09 };
```

How would I split the byte[] everywhere "0xc0" exists?

Comment: please show some source... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Windows Forms.

Comment: why not just going through the array and copying it to another till you get to the 0xc0... then you do with it whatever you want and carry on with the rest of the sequence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply enumerate over your buffer and return a subset whenever you reach the byte to split on:

```
IEnumerable<byte[]> Split(byte splitByte, byte[] buffer) 
{
    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
    foreach(byte b in buffer) 
    {
        if (b != splitByte)
            bytes.Add(b);
        else
        {
            yield return bytes.ToArray();
            bytes.Clear();
        }
    }
    yield return bytes.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You can use `ArraySegment<byte>` instead. That would mean you wouldn't have to copy the bytes all over the place.